# obtener el index de mi tabla con vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs, javascript-objeto

el html es una tabla de donde al agregar el contenido me lo pinta en el html a su ves lo recorro con V-for

```
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) of add" :key="index">
         <td>{{index}}</td>
        <td>{{item.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{item.apellido}}</td>
        <td>{{item.direc}}</td>
        <td>{{item.estado}}</td>
        <td>{{item.seleccion}}</td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <a
              href="#"
              role="button"
              @click="confirm = true"
              class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm"
            >
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-2x" style="color:DodgerBlue"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

lo estoy ejecuntando con un modal que esta afuera de mi table

```
<mdb-container>
  <!-- confirm modal -->
  <mdb-modal :show="confirm" @close="confirm = false" size="sm" class="text-center" danger>
    <mdb-modal-header center :close="false">
      <p class="heading">Are you sure?</p>
    </mdb-modal-header>
    <mdb-modal-body>
      <mdb-icon icon="times" size="4x" class="animated rotateIn" />
    </mdb-modal-body>
    <mdb-modal-footer centers>
      <mdb-btn outline="danger" @click="confirm = false" v-on:click="BorrarEstado(index)">Yes</mdb-btn>
      <mdb-btn color="danger" @click="confirm = false">No</mdb-btn>
    </mdb-modal-footer>
  </mdb-modal>
</mdb-container>
```

el javascript no se como capturar el index de mi lista, que manera puedo capturar el index???

```
 BorrarEstado:function(index){
  console.log('editar', index)
}
```

Comment: Porque quieres hacer eso?

Comment: para poder obtener el index, y poder ejecutar borrar ese dato